# queryselectorall does not return all elements

Tags: selectors-api

I am using vb.net and the following code

```
...
Imports Knyaz.Optimus
Imports Knyaz.Optimus.Dom.Elements
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports Knyaz.Optimus.Dom.Interfaces
...
Dim coll As ReadOnlyCollection(Of IElement)
...
coll = _engine.Document.QuerySelectorAll("*")
```

Where _engine is the Kynaz engine object.

The code runs without error but coll only contains the first 68 elements.  It stops when it reaches a  element within a  element.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: that should read a style element within a ul element - the chevrons were removed when I posted the text

Comment: This has been logged as a bug on github by the developer - fix in release 2.3